# Couple of stack operations (a pop+a push) vs a Hash Table alternative

Tags: linux, hash, stack, hashtable

I have a process and it's defined `stack`. Now while pushing an item on to `stack`, I need to check if a same/similar item already exists. If not - push the new item.
This involves two stack operations

1. pop a similar type item, compare if
   its the same as item being pushed
2. then push the latest.

My question is - is the cost incurred worth it or should I go for maintaining a hash table for my stack entries to make this decision easier.?
Otherwise put, how costly are the stack operations..?

One more thing on a flat memory model like LINUX, would it be absolutely wrong to increase the preallocated stack size on need basis (say by realloc) ?

Comment: well, the original implementation is in SDL (a language that effectively describes the state machines.!) but nevertheless is compiled on gcc, meaning its first translated into its C equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

clearly the stack option is toll taking as a lot of unnecessary time is wasted on processing which is not required. hash based approach is better as hash table is the fastest way to search for anything( here for you it would be the record that is similar to the new record that u are planning to add to the memory). Hash is always the best way to go, even in operating system designing people use hash table to provide optimal performance.